# convert c++ CString.Format syntax to .NET string syntax (variable leading widths and decimal places)

Tags: c#, c++, string

How can I convert the following C++ CString code to a C# .NET equivalent?

```
CString str;
int leading_width  = 5;
int decimal_places = 2;
int val            = 53.4789;

str.Format("%*.*d", leading_width, decimal_places, val);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a variable number of decimal places, convert `val` to a string using `val.ToString`, then pad the value using `String.PadLeft`.

```
int leading_width  = 5;
int decimal_places = 2;
int val            = 53.4789;

string str = val.ToString("N" + decimal_places);
str = str.PadLeft(leading_width);
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize the ToString method could take format arguments - that certainly simplifies things.  I was originally going along the path of "{0, {1}, D{2}}" which unfortunately isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the code is to convert an integer or other number to a string...

```
string NumString = val.ToString();
```

Managed Code (which c# is) has this nifty ToString method that every object in the code has inherited from the `object` class.

There are various and sundry formatting rules that can be applied to the to final result regarding rules and padding.

See this page for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

**Edit**

How about this code

```
String.Format("%{0," + String.Format("{0}:D{1}", leading_width, decimal_places) + "}", val);
```

or you can leave off the "%" and use "P" instead of "D"

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer.  I knew it was simple I just couldn't figure out the {0, {1}, D{2}} syntax.